# Failed (vanilla JS) to modify html <style> in javscript via a ternary operator function

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

**My guess: This might be a problem with reading the exports.**

Full work here https://repl.it/@thelmaijemma/MiniGenuineTwintext

So I have some HTML to display 5 stars and I want to highlight a specific number of them YELLOW according to a set value via javascript (because later I will add a function to hightlight via hover)

html:

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vanilla App</title>
    <style>
         .star-class .star{
            font-size: 5rem;
            color: gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Rating App</h2>
    <div class="star-class" id="rating1" role="rater" data-rating="1">
    <!--div.star-class#rating1-->
    <span class="star" data-value="1">&#9733;</span>
    <span class="star" data-value="2">&#9733;</span>
    <span class="star" data-value="3">&#9733;</span>
    <span class="star" data-value="4">&#9733;</span>
    <span class="star" data-value="5">&#9733;</span>
</div>
<div class="star-class" id="rating2" role="rater" data-rating="5">
    <!-- div.star-class#rating1 -->
    <span class="star" data-value="1">&#9733;</span>
    <span class="star" data-value="2">&#9733;</span>
    <span class="star" data-value="3">&#9733;</span>
    <span class="star" data-value="4">&#9733;</span>
    <span class="star" data-value="5">&#9733;</span>
</div>
<script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

And rater.js (in js folder)

```
export function Rater(ratingElement){
    const stars = ratingElement.querySelectorAll('.star');

    const resetRating = ev => {
        const current = ratingElement.getAttribute('data-rating');
        higlighter(current);
    }

    const higlighter = (rating) => {
        stars.forEach( starry => {
           rating >= starry.getAttribute('data-value') ? 'yellow' : 'gray';
          
        });
    }

    resetRating();

}
```

and the main script.js:

```
import { Rater } from './rater.js';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    const raters = document.querySelectorAll('[role=rater]');
    raters.forEach(rater => {
        new Rater(rater)
        // using html, perform this function from the rater function import
        // for each dom object with the query selector role rate
    })
})
```

Comment: Using `>=` will not work; I don't know what you expect that to do, but it is valid syntax but it won't do anything.

Comment: I am trying to highlight the star yellow if the "data-rating" for the div is greater than or equal to the "data-value" for the span star HTML

Comment: Right, but that expression is not going to do anything at all. It will perform a comparison, but the result of the comparison is completely ignored.

Comment: Thanks I went ahead and make that change and it fixed the function. here is the working code thanks  const higlighter = (rating) => {
        stars.forEach( star => {
           star.style.color =
          rating >= star.getAttribute('data-value') ? 'yellow' : 'gray';
          
        });
    }